# Text box -> start typing right away instead of clicking the box

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have a search bar, and when I open the search bar I want to start typing right away and do not want to click on the text box for that to happen.

I tried to use `myTextBoxId.click()` ( because when you click it, you can start typing ) but it didn't work.

Comment: Use `myTextBoxId.focus()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have to

```
document.getElementById(" <put your Id here> ").focus();
```

to set focus on the given element.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the focus once you load the page, or trigger the focus on keydown (this way even if you set the focus out of the input - when you start typing the focus will get there again).

```js
$(function() {
  $('#searchbox').focus();

  $(document).on('keydown', function() {
    $('#searchbox').focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchbox" />
```

Answer (score 2):

since you've got 17 of the same answer, how about a new one!

HTML5 has an autofocus attribute that does this. no JS required.

```
<input type='text' autofocus>
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autofocus).

Comment: Nice one :) got +1 from me on that.

Comment: Note: this will not work in an iframe. it can't steal focus from the parent window. (nudge to whoever tried to edit the question to put it in the little code editor)

Comment: back at you @Dekel

Comment: This might set the focus even before it is supposed to. And, unless you dont insert it again into the DOM, it won't set the focus on opening the search bar, if you've had the focus on something else before. So I'd rather go with the JS solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `myTextBox.focus()` to achieve this. Note that you can call `focus()` after `myTextBox` variable is set to point to your actual text box. See: [`HTMLElement focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.focus()` instead of `.click()`

```js
var myTextBoxId = document.getElementById("myTextBoxId")
myTextBoxId.focus();
```

```html
<input id="myTextBoxId" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If  `<input id="myTextBoxId" />`, you can use following scripts

**Jquery**:

```
$(function() {
 $("#myTextBoxId").focus();
});
```

**Javascript**:

```
window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById("myTextBoxId").focus();
};
```

or

```
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('myTextBoxId').focus();">
```